For loop not incrementing a global variable?
new to coding here so hopefully someone can help. I'm attempting to populate a matrix using For loops. I was able to populate it properly in an early version with 2 nested For Loops but the performance was terrible. I switched the code to Pine Script's recommended math.sum(). Columns 2, 3, and 4 (indexed 1,2,3) are doing a count based on a price stored in the first column.
I originally had the math.sums embedded in the For loop but was getting the warning about extracting the call from the scope so moved them to the Global level. Now it appears my Get_Matrix that calls the first column for the calculation won't update with the For Loops increments.
I've tried everything including brute forcing the matrix.get row to increment manually instead of using the For Loop and I still get the same results on every row.
The results on row 1 are correct, any thoughts on why they keep repeating themselves to the remaining rows as well?
//Inputs and Variables
Rangesize = input.float(1,"Range Size",[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5])  
Rangemax = 549  
Stepfunction = input.float(0.25,"Step Function",[0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,1])  
Wickmax = input.float(0.75,"Max Wick Size")  
LookbackPeriod = 200  
Wickratethreshold = 0.4  


varip Pricematrix = matrix.new<float>(10,6,0.0)  
var j = 0  
var Get_Matrix = matrix.get(Pricematrix,0,0)  
RTouch = math.sum(Get_Matrix > open and Get_Matrix <= high and Get_Matrix >= (high - Wickmax) and Get_Matrix > close ? 1 : 0, LookbackPeriod)  
STouch = math.sum(Get_Matrix < close and Get_Matrix >= low and Get_Matrix <= (low + Wickmax) and Get_Matrix < open ? 1 : 0, LookbackPeriod)  
CTouch = math.sum(Get_Matrix >= low and Get_Matrix <= high ? 1 : 0, LookbackPeriod)  


for var i = 0 to matrix.rows(Pricematrix) - 1  
    Get_Matrix := matrix.get(Pricematrix,i,0)  
    j := i  
    matrix.set(Pricematrix,i,0,Rangemax - i * Stepfunction)
    
    matrix.set(Pricematrix,i,1,RTouch)  
    
    // Third Column [Support]   
    matrix.set(Pricematrix,i,2,STouch)  
        
    //Fourth Column [Candles]  
    matrix.set(Pricematrix,i,3,CTouch) 

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!
~Budding Pine Scriptor
I've tried embedding the math.sums, extracting them, isolating For loops, For...in loops, manually setting the variables for the matrix.get calls instead of relying on the For Loop increments, changing the Get_Matrix to a var.
I will say manually assigning the row index to the Get_Matrix function does yield the correct result for that particular value in column 1, it just repeats those same values on all rows.
